# Is O(nlog(2,n)) in O(n^2 )?

Tags: logarithms

Trying to do Big O proofs and I'm stuck on this proof.

Need to prove if O(nlog(2,n)) is in O(n^2)

After playing around with it I get

log(2,n)/n <= c but I'm not too sure what to do after or how to conclude the proof

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Do you want to prove that $n\log_2(n)\in\mathcal O(n^2)$ instead? Or is $\mathcal O(n\log_2(n))\subseteq \mathcal O(n^2)$ what you want to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since
$${n\log(n)\over n^2 } = {\log(n)\over n} \to 0, $$
as $n\to\infty$.  In fact it's $o(n^2)$.  Since ${\log(n)\over n}\to 0$, this sequence is bounded, so be reassured.